# EditText con mensaje de error en Android

Tags: java, android, android-layout, material-design

En la [guia de diseño Material Design de Google](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-style), para mostrar un mensaje de error cuando un campo está mal rellenado, se utiliza un mensaje de error debajo del componente, me pregunto cómo se establece ese texto y que método lanza para su aparición, cómo también posteriormente ocultarlo si los datos nuevamente puestos el usuario son correctos.

Dejo la imágen que puede ser más claro de lo que quiero decir
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usas un `TextInputLayout` y utilizas `setError()` para definir el mensaje, `setErrorEnabled()` para habilitarlo, por ejemplo:

```
//Validación de error en email, valida texto que ingresa el usuario en el EditText.
boolean emailError = validaEditTextEmail();

//Dependiendo del valor booleando al validar el email, muestra el mensaje:
TextInputLayout tilEmail = (TextInputLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.til_email);
tilEmail.setError(emailError ? "Ingrese un correo válido" : "");
tilEmail.setErrorEnabled(emailError);
```

Al detectar la validación un email incorrecto se habilita el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agrego un ejemplo tde TextInputLayout para el ejemplo anterior:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/til_email"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:paddingTop="5dp"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/mi_email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/preg_correo"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

En este ejemplo, la validación se realiza sobre el texto introducido en el  `EdiText` con id `mi_email`, en base al valor obtenido determinamos mostrar o no el mensaje por medio del  `TextInputLayout`.