# setError() con valores desde carpeta String

Tags: android, edittext

Cuando intenta fijar un mensaje para que se muestre en un `EditText` con `setError()`,

```
 textEdit.setError(texto_mensaje);
```

quiero que este mensaje sea desde la carpeta String, sin embargo me marca error.

Comment: agrega por favor como lo cargas desde Strings.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el mensaje simplemente debes usar el contexto por ejemplo **si te encuentras en una `Activity` puedes usar `getApplicationContext()` como contexto para obtener el recurso**.

```
String texto_mensaje = getApplicationContext().getResources().getString(R.id.<key mensaje en strings.xml>);
textEdit.setError(texto_mensaje);
textEdit.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

Si te encuentras en una `Activity` usa `getActivity()` como contexto:

```
String texto_mensaje = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.id.<key mensaje en strings.xml>);    
textEdit.setError(texto_mensaje);
textEdit.setErrorEnabled(true);
```

---

Recuerda que es importante usar `setErrorEnabled(true)` para habilitar el mensaje.

Revisa:

[EditText con mensaje de error en Android](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/7982/edittext-con-mensaje-de-error-en-android/7983#7983)